# Getting Alpine Expression Error on calling function

Tags: javascript, alpine.js

I'm trying to make sortable divs with AlpineJS, but get an error:

```
Alpine Expression Error: moveLeft is not defined

Expression: "moveLeft($refs.box3)"
```

On code:

```
<div x-data>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" x-ref="box1">
      <button @click.prevent="moveLeft($refs.box1)">Move Left</button>
      <button @click.prevent="moveRight($refs.box1)">Move Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box" x-ref="box2">
      <button @click.prevent="moveLeft($refs.box2)">Move Left</button>
      <button @click.prevent="moveRight($refs.box2)">Move Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box" x-ref="box3">
      <button @click.prevent="moveLeft($refs.box3)">Move Left</button>
      <button @click.prevent="moveRight($refs.box3)">Move Right</button>
    </div>
    <!-- add more boxes as needed -->
  </div>
</div>

<script>
  window.onload = function () {
    const app = Alpine.data('app', {
      moveLeft: function (element) {
        const prevSibling = element.previousElementSibling;
        if (prevSibling) {
          element.before(prevSibling);
        }
      },
      moveRight: function (element) {
        const nextSibling = element.nextElementSibling;
        if (nextSibling) {
          nextSibling.before(element);
        }
      }
    });
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create an Alpine.js component with [`Alpine.data()`](https://alpinejs.dev/globals/alpine-data) you need to provide the component name in `x-data`. Furthermore you need to return the component's data (since it is a function definition). I also fixed the insert before/after logic in your code, see the example below:

```html
<script defer src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.min.js"></script>
<div x-data="app">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="box" x-ref="box1">A -
      <button @click.prevent="moveLeft($refs.box1)">Move Left</button>
      <button @click.prevent="moveRight($refs.box1)">Move Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box" x-ref="box2">B -
      <button @click.prevent="moveLeft($refs.box2)">Move Left</button>
      <button @click.prevent="moveRight($refs.box2)">Move Right</button>
    </div>
    <div class="box" x-ref="box3">C -
      <button @click.prevent="moveLeft($refs.box3)">Move Left</button>
      <button @click.prevent="moveRight($refs.box3)">Move Right</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
  Alpine.data('app', () => ({
    moveLeft(element) {
      const prevSibling = element.previousElementSibling;
      if (prevSibling) {
        prevSibling.before(element);
      }
    },
    moveRight(element) {
      const nextSibling = element.nextElementSibling;
      if (nextSibling) {
        nextSibling.after(element);
      }
    }
  }))
})
</script>
```